# Const correctness for data handled by not const classes

Tags: c++, c++03, const-correctness

I want to use class-oriented design to efficiently and cleanly handle data on an embedded platform. I should not create new objects on the stack (or at least be very economic) so I intend to pass my data as reference to helper classes and manipulate it within there (also to achieve proper encapsulation).

The following code is a very stripped down example of the problem I'm facing.

```
#include "Vector.h"

void DoSomething(float* a1, const float* a2)
{
  // some code

  Vector v1(a1[0], a1[1], a1[2]);
  Vector v2(a2[0], a2[1], a2[2]);
  v1.MakeEqual(v2);

  // more code
}

int main()
{
  float x1[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
  float x2[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };
  DoSomething(x1, x2);
  return 0;
}
```

The `Vector`-Class is defined in the header file:

```
#pragma once
class Vector
{
public:
  Vector(float& _x, float& _y, float& _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
  {}

  Vector(const float& _x, const float& _y, const float& _z) 
      :x(const_cast<float&>(_x)), y(const_cast<float&>(_y)), z(const_cast<float&>(_z)) //works, but looks not good
  {}

  ~Vector(){};

  void MakeEqual(const Vector& other)
  {
    x = other.x;
    y = other.y;
    z = other.z;
  }

private:
  float& x;
  float& y;
  float& z;
};
```

My data is defined somewhere extern (`main`-function) and then passed as pointers to a function `DoSomething`. Inside this function vector objects are wrapped around the data to help doing some vector-typical stuff (rotating, cross-products, etc...). Now I want to be const-correct and pass the data which is not intended to be changed as `const` but when the vector v2 is created I have the compiler complaining that he `cannot convert argument 1 from 'const float' to 'float &'`. I understand what he wants to say, but how can I solve this? The vector method only makes sense when I am using it on vectors but the constructor of the vector `v2` does not know that I'm actually not manipulating the data of v2.

One way to solve this is shown in the code with a `const_cast` in a second constructor, but I have the feeling that this is not good style, since I'm casting away my legitimate const data. Another way would be to define a second class `ConstVector` but this seem weird as well.

I have to mention that due to compiler restrictions I am bound to the `C++03` standard so unfortunately I cannot use too modern language features. Also `stl`-containers are (probably) not available since I cannot control how, when and where memory is allocated.

Comment: your `MakeEqual` *is* changing `x,y,z`, so you are (able to) changing the value.

Comment: although not recommended for this case, you can have something like `class const_vector` to use with const values.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Vector(float& _x, float& _y, float& _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
```

That does not work well. For example, you can't use:

```
Vector v1(0, 0, 0);
```

Also, you are not able to use

```
Vector v1(a1[0], a1[1], a1[2]);
```

since `a1[0]` evaluates to a `const float&`, not a `float&`.

That's poorly designed interface. Change the arguments to simple values:

```
Vector(float _x, float _y, float _z) :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
```

Comment: I guess OP want the `Vector`s act like wrapper (can change the origin array), so `Vector::Vector(float,float,float)` may not meet OP's need (for `v1`).

Comment: @appleapple, I hope not. The use of temporary objects on the stack, such as `Vector`s would not be very helpful to perform the kinds of computation they hope to do. I'll wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @appleapple, you are right. I use the Vector class only to manipulate the existing data in a certain way. After I did that I can totally ignore the vector since it does not contain data by its own. It might be possible to pass the data as values like proposed and in the end copy the result of the vector operation back to the data. More load on the stack but probably a better solution than my current one...